# Find the range of values of $t$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> Find the range of values of $t$ for which $$2\sin t=\frac{1-2x+5x^2}{3x^2-2x-1}$$ where $\displaystyle t\in\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

I can't comprehend what the question is actually asking. What does it mean by the **range of values of $t$**$?$

I've solved for $x$ and have concluded that the domain of $x$ is $(-\infty,-1]\cup\left[\frac{3-2\sqrt5}{11},\frac{3+2\sqrt5}{11}\right]\cup[3,\infty)$

How can I determine the range of $t?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are asked to determine the set
$\{t\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\mid\exists x\in\Bbb R,2\sin t=\frac{1-2x+5x^2}{3x^2-2x-1}\}.$ You did the converse, finding the $x$'s for which $\exists t.$

Comment: Oh ic thanks ...I also just realised this... fortunately I got the correct answer @AnneBauval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of values of $t$ here is basically asking you to find the intersection of the ranges of the two functions. Why this is true is because let $y$ be in the range of $2\sin(t)$ then $y$ is also in the range of that rational function, so $y$ is in the intersection of their ranges. Since $t\in [\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ we have that $2\sin(t)\in [-2, 2]$ so we need to find the values of the rational function that lie inside $[-2, 2]$. You can proceed form here using calculus, however I cheated and used desmos.

One bound is easy to get by letting it go to infinity on either side so we get the interval $[\frac{5}{3}, 2]$ is definitely in the range, the other part can be found be just finding the maxima of the rational function in the interval between the roots of the denominator, you get the other interval for the range is $[-2, -0.618]$

Answer (score 1):

The right function over $x$ has singularities where its denominator equals $0$. Happily, applying the quadratic formula, we get roots $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-3*-1}}{3}=\frac{1\pm4}{3}\in\{1,\frac{-1}{3}\}$, so the right side is $\frac{5*x^2-2*x+1}{(x-1)*(3*x+1)}$. At each singularity, it will change sign, and the numerator's roots are $\frac{1\pm2*i}{5}$, so the sign depends entirely on the denominator (and is negative between its roots and positive outside). We can take the partial fraction expansion,
$$f(x)=\frac{5*x^2-2*x+1}{(x-1)*(3*x+1)}=\frac{c_0}{x-1}+\frac{c_1}{3*x+1}+c_2\\
\iff5*x^2-2*x+1=(3*x+1)*c_0+(x-1)*c_1+(3*x^2-2*x-1)*c_2\\
\iff\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&-1\\3&1&-2\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}c_0\\c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}\\
\iff\begin{pmatrix}c_0\\c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&-1\\3&1&-2\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}^{-1}*\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac{-5}{3}\\\frac{5}{3}\end{pmatrix}\\
\iff f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{5}{9*x+3}+\frac{5}{3}\\
\iff f'(x)=\frac{5}{(3*x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\\
f'(x)=0\iff(x-1)^2=\frac{(3*x+1)^2}{5}\iff\pm(x-1)=\frac{\pm(3*x+1)}{\sqrt{5}}$$
These can be either the same sign or different, giving us
$$\iff x=\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
-2-\sqrt{5}\ :\ x-1=\frac{+3*x+1}{\sqrt{5}}\\
-2+\sqrt{5}\ :\ x-1=\frac{-3*x-1}{\sqrt{5}}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$The first one lies outside of our singularities so provides a minimum, the second between so provides a maximum, evaluating them provides $f\left(-2-\sqrt{5}\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $f\left(-2+\sqrt{5}\right)=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. The limit as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ is $\frac{5}{3}$, obtained by neglecting all but the leading coefficients, and doesn't provide a minimum.

We know $\left|\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right|>1$, so for our purposes, $x\leq\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. $\sin$ is a strictly-increasing function, so $\frac{-\pi}{2}\leq t\leq\mathrm{asin}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)$.$$
\mathrm{asin}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)=\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^2}+i*\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)}{i}\\
=\frac{\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{16-1+2*\sqrt{5}-5}}{4}+i*\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)}{i}\\
=\frac{\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}}{2}+i*\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)}{i}\\
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\frac{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}}{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}}{2}}\right)
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2*\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}}\right)\\
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}*(1+\sqrt{5})}\right)\\
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^2}{2*\sqrt{5}*(1+\sqrt{5})}}\right)
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)*\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}}{2*\sqrt{5}}}\right)\\
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)*\left(\sqrt{5}-3\right)}{4*\sqrt{5}}}\right)\\
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-2}{\sqrt{5}}}\right)
=\mathrm{atan}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\right)
$$However, hereafter the easiest deterministic way to find that it equals $\frac{\pi}{10}$ is to either use $\tan\left(t\right)=\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}$ and apply the multiple-angle formula upon it until you get $0$, or check the original $\sin$ output against the roots of the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

You thus obtain $t\in[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{-\pi}{10}]$.